# Commented out line cancels all proceeding styles in css file

Tags: css

This is a weird question, but what is the reasoning behind it? Take this block of CSS for example:

```
.test {
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
} // wot

.derp {color:#FF0000;}
```

This will **not** apply the `.derp` styling to the document - [**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/44z18dfa/)

Now why would this be happening? I've read the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) in relation to comments which state *"you should use"* `/*comment here*/` for single and multi-line comments, but why would we be able to comment out other stuff in css then? (*Within `{}`*) Like so:

```
.class {
    //background: #FF0000;
}
```

Just for completeness' sake, here's a [**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/44z18dfa/1/) of the CSS being applied when the comment is removed.

---

I'm asking this is because I just did something like this and it didn't throw any errors in the console or anything like that so I was just wondering what causes this and is it general practice as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment is taken to be everything until the next closing `}` which is your `.derp` style. Subsequent styles would be applied. You can see the effect of these comments;

```
.test {
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
} //wot

.derp {color:#FF0000;} 

.derp {color:#00FF00;} //wot

.derp {color:#0000FF;}
```

Here the red style and final blue style are ignored and green is applied; https://jsfiddle.net/44z18dfa/9/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best explanation.

```
.test {
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}

//wot .derp {color:#ff0000;} 

 .derp {color:#00ff00;}

//wot .derp {color:#0000ff;}
```